# Angular directive to execute a function after HTML element has been loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code in some controller:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect)
```

This code executes before "#fileInput" is loaded. I fixed it:

```
  $timeout(->
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect)
  , 1000)
```

But it isn't a good solution, because page loading may take more than 1000 milliseconds. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe attach model to the input and use $watch to check changes?

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', function(){
        alert('yeah!');
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that #fileInput will be in the DOM when it is called.  Just because the document.ready() is invoked does not guarantee that a particular element has been added (elements can be added after document.ready fires).  Best not to mix jQuery patterns with Angular.

Comment: @JoeEnzminger , yes, I agree with you, my jQuery-style variant isn't the best solution at all (from angular-way viewpoint). But it is suitable in most cases for quick fix in already existing bad-written code.  Of course, your solution is more general, written in "angular-way", and it will work in all cases, but I found, that sometimes it is preferable to write small, simple and clear solution for resolving simple issue, than to write complicated directive. (Also, I never use  $scope.$emit, because it is antipattern, in my humble opinion).

Answer (score 0):

The first red flag is "the following code in some controller".  You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM from a controller.

Without knowing more specifics of your application (a plunkr would be helpful), the best advice would be to wrap the functionality that is using a file input in a directive.  The link function of a directive will have a reference to the file input element that you can use to wire up events.  You can then $emit those events so that the appropriate controller can handle them (or, alternatively, call event handler methods that you pass into the directive).

As a general rule, you should never have to use an #id selector in an angular application.

```
.directive('fileUpload', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<input type="file"></input>',
        scope: {
        },
        controller: function () {
        },
        compile: function ($templateElement, $templateAttributes) {
            return function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                //$element is the input element
                $element.on('change', function(evt) {
                   $scope.$apply(function() {
                      $scope.$emit('fileUpload.change', evt);
                   });
                }
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then in your markup:

```
<file-upload></file-upload>
```